# Executing SQL code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have script to create database and tables(around 50 tables). When I copy paste the script to SQL Management studio it runs fine, but when I try to run from my app I am getting an SQL Exception.

Here is my code:

```
string enterRecordsScript = "my sql script";
SqlCommand enterRecords = new SqlCommand(enterRecordsScript, connection);
enterRecords.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And here is the exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

Here is the Script:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST3
GO
USE Test3;

CREATE TABLE [SAShoppingInvoice]
(
    [Guid] uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    [Number] nvarchar(50),
    [DateOfShopping] datetime,
    [SubTotal] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [PSubTotal] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [Freight] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [Total] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [ATotal] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [PriceLevel] nvarchar(20),
    [SummaryTotal] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
);


CREATE TABLE [SAShoppingInvoiceDetail]
(
    [Guid] uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    [Number] nvarchar(50),
    [UnitPrice] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [Quantity] decimal(18,2) DEFAULT 0,
    [Description] nvarchar(100),
);



ALTER TABLE [SAShoppingInvoiceDetail]
ADD ShoppingInvoiceGuid uniqueidentifier
CONSTRAINT FK_SAShoppingInvoice_ShoppingInvoice_To_SAShoppingInvoiceDetail_ShoppingInvoice
FOREIGN KEY (ShoppingInvoiceGuid) 
REFERENCES [SAShoppingInvoice](Guid);

GO
CREATE VIEW SAShoppingInvoice_SummaryTotal WITH SCHEMABINDING AS SELECT ShoppingInvoiceGuid,  SUM(ISNULL(Quantity,0)*ISNULL(UnitPrice,0)) as SummaryTotal, COUNT_BIG(*) as CountBig
FROM dbo.SAShoppingInvoiceDetail Group By ShoppingInvoiceGuid;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_SAShoppingInvoiceSummaryTotal ON SAShoppingInvoice_SummaryTotal(ShoppingInvoiceGuid);
```

Why running the script from my app is making a problem?

Comment: You will have to share the sql script.

Comment: like is says `CREATE VIEW` must be the first statement in a query batch. means that you should use a `Go` before `CREATE VIEW` statement

Comment: @faridbekran No, the fact that `GO` is included is the problem. Putting more `GO`s in it won't solve anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GO` is not valid SQL. It is used by some specific tools (such as SSMS) to split a large text file into multiple separate commands. Within your own programs, that becomes your responsibility.

If you have a text file

```
a
GO
b
GO
c
GO
```

then if you want to execute this using `SqlCommand` objects, you need three commands, one containing `a`, one containing `b`, and one containing `c`. None of those three includes `GO`.